# Php array - can't get value from array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$data = '{"name":"CocaCola","price":1,"sync":0,"id":10792}';
$data = json_decode($data);

print_r((array)$data);
//Array ( [name] => CocaCola [price] => 1 [sync] => 0 [id] => 10792 )

print_r((array)$data["id"]);
//nothing?
```

This piece of code is not logic for me. Can I get any explanation of this behaviour and how to fix it?

Comment: With `json_decode($data)`, you'll be getting an object. To get an associative array, set the second parameter as `TRUE`. See the [documentation for `json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) for more information.

Comment: The output shown in your question isn't correct either. The second statement would print out an error "*Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array*". ([Enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) if you haven't already.)

Comment: Use `var_dump` in order to get info about type structure you are dealing with.

Comment: Ok I understand now. I have object but I tried to use it like array. Thanks for help and -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(array)$data["id"]
```

This is executed as

```
(array)($data["id"])
```

I.e. the result of `$data['id']` is cast to an array; not `$data` cast to an array and then its `id` index accessed.

If you want an array, use `json_decode(..., true)`. Otherwise work with objects as objects instead of casting them to arrays all the time over and over.

Comment: @deceze , isn't this a bit too complicated question for 200k user? Maybe you should stick with "missing semicolon" questions for now.

Comment: @tereško Yeah, feeling a bit out of my depth here... ^_^;; But who else was going to deliver this explanation...?

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode` returns an object with the properties, not an array.

https://www.php.net/json_decode

`mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )`

Pass true (bool value) to the second parameter in the json_decode function to get an associative array back. Then you will be able to access it as an array.

Alternatively, you could access the properties using the `->` operator.

So in your case:

```
print_r($data->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this

```
print_r((array)$data["id"]);
```

try instead

```
$d = (array)$data;
print_r($d["id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using json_decode returns an object (eg. $data->id).
If you want it to return an array, use json_decode($data, true);